# How to send UDP datagram to different network in java?

Tags: udp

I have made an UDP client server program in java. It is working well in localhost and in the same router/ network.
But when I am running my UDP server program in my laptop connected to internet and running my UDP client program in my lab (on different network), then it is not working.
Is there any way to send UDP datagram over the network from one system to another?

Comment: it's all just IP. shouldn't matter what IP you use, as long as the other host is reachable from yours.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad to answer here without writing a whole textbook chapter, but in a few words there is going to have to be a route from point A to point B, which in your current setup is either missing or broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in theory it should be working just the same. It's still IP.

In reality, routers with NAT exist. For example, if you address an UDP packet to your home PC's public IP address, it actually is addressed at your router. The router does not know which local IP he should address the packet to and discards the packet.

The solution: Configure UDP port forwardings for routers on both ends.

Comment: Can you please tell me ho to configure port forwarding for routers.